# MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s) when insert row from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-insert

While working on a system I'm creating, I attempted to use the following query in my project:

```
INSERT INTO wpr9_posts ( `post_date`,`post_content`,`post_title`,`post_status`,`post_type` ) 
VALUES ((SELECT '2020-08-28 18:30:43' as post_date,`image`,`name`,'publish' as post_status,'post' as post_type FROM `play` WHERE `catid` = 863 ))
```

This query inserts a row from a table to another table.

Is there a simple fix to this, or another way to write my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `values` keyword when using an insert-select statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO wpr9_posts ( `post_date`,`post_content`,`post_title`,`post_status`,`post_type` ) 
SELECT '2020-08-28 18:30:43' as post_date,`image`,`name`,'publish' as post_status,'post' as post_type FROM `play` WHERE `catid` = 863
```